# STL map with custom class comparator not working

Tags: c++, class, c++11, dictionary

I have a map which has a class as key.

In this class I overloaded the `<` operator, I read here that the map will automatically use that for comparison and sorting.

I get the following error when compiling:

> Error 1   error C2664: 'std::pair::pair(const
>   std::pair &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from
>   'Position' to 'Position *const &' e:\program files\visual studio 2013
>   ultimate\vc\include\xmemory0

I don't get what that really means or how I can avoid it. It doesn't highlight anything in my code either.

Here is my code, my class is coordinates, I want them to be sorted from left to right and top to bottom, but the logic isn't the problem here.

There's obviously more stuff in the Position files, but I think these are the relevant parts.

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
  std::map<Position*, int> karte;
  Position p1;
  p1.setX(0);
  p1.setY(0);

  Position p2;
  p2.setX(0);
  p2.setY(1);

  Position p3;
  p3.setX(1);
  p3.setY(0);

  Position p4;
  p4.setX(1);
  p4.setY(1);

  karte.emplace(p1, 1);
  karte.emplace(p2, 2);
  karte.emplace(p3, 3);
  karte.emplace(p4, 4);

  for (auto& x : karte)
  {
    std::cout << x.first->toString() << ": " << x.second << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Position.h

```
bool operator<(const Position&) const;
```

Position.cpp

```
bool Position::operator<(const Position &position) const
{
  if ((x_ < position.x_) && (y_ == position.y_))
  {
    return true;
  }
  if (x_ > position.x_ && y_ < position.y_)
  {
    return true;
  }
  if (x_ == position.x_ && y_ < position.y_)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your map's keys are pointers. Your comparator doesn't compare pointers.

Comment: You are trying to store `Position` in a container declared to store `Position*`

Comment: In fact, the custom comparator isn't even called in this case.

Comment: How could I change the comparator to be called? The map must have `Position*` in it, or else a lot of other code won't work.

Comment: Raw pointers are seldom a good idea in STL containers. Maybe std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr instead? And of course, if the keys are small, just insert key by value, no need for smart pointers then.

Comment: @CGuy: If you really want to use pointers as keys, change the comparison operator to a nonmember `bool operator<(Position*,Position*)` to compare pointers. And change the arguments of `emplace` to `&p1` etc. But using pointers as keys it probably a recipe for disaster; think again about why you want to do that.

Comment: @MikeSeymour What do you mean by nonmember?

Comment: @CGuy: Not a member function of `Position`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Where would I place it then? And how would the map still know to use that for comparing two `Position` classes?

Comment: @CGuy: Declare it in the same header as `Position`, outside the class declaration. Define it in the source file, just like you're already doing. The map will know to use it because it's been declared.

Comment: @MikeSeymour you can't redefine an operator for pointers

Comment: @AntonSavin: You're right. Another reason not to use pointers. But if you really, really want to use pointers, you'll have to define a function or class to compare them, rather than overloading `operator<`. Sorry for misleading you.

Comment: Thank you for your help all, I realize using pointers that way is bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *need* the map's keys to be pointers, you can create your own comparator and pass it to the map:

```
struct PositionPointerLesser
{
  bool operator() (Position *lhs, Position *rhs) const
  {
    return *lhs < *rhs;  // This calls the operator < in your class
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::map<Position*, int, PositionPointerLesser> karte;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: `std::binary_function` is deprecated and there's no need to inherit from it.

Comment: @AntonSavin Good point, removed. It's a habit I've learned from dealing with pre-11 compilers, which sometimes need the extra info provided by the typedefs it brings.

Answer (score 3):

Redefine your map as:

```
std::map<Position, int> karte;
```

The compilation error is because you're trying to insert a `pair<Position, int>` into the map:

```
Position p1;
<snip>
karte.emplace(p1, 1);
```

and you've declared your map as `map<Position*, int>`

Comment: Thank you too, unfortunately a lot of code relies on the map with Position as a pointer, not written by me.